# Merging multiple branches with git

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have 2 local branches called "develop" and "master"; they are similar. On my company's server there's one "main" repo (production) and several branches that were made by other developers:

```
$ git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/some-test
  remotes/origin/feature1
  remotes/origin/feature2
  remotes/origin/master
```

How can I merge `remotes/origin/feature1` and `remotes/origin/feature2` into my local "master" branch, copy that all into "develop" and start working with actual code in my "develop" branch?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull origin feature1 feature2`
3. `git checkout develop`
4. `git pull . master` (or maybe `git rebase ./master`)

The first command changes your current branch to `master`.

The second command pulls in changes from the remote `feature1` and `feature2` branches. This is an "octopus" merge because it merges more than 2 branches. You could also do two normal merges if you prefer.

The third command switches you back to your `develop` branch.

The fourth command pulls the changes from local `master` to `develop`.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Note that `git pull` will automatically do a `fetch` so you don't need to do it manually. It's pretty much equivalent to `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

Comment: What's the resulting difference between this method and just using two merges? Do you you get a single merge commit with all three branches as parents? Also, this will presumably fail if the merges aren't clean, right? So a `git merge feature1 feature2` might be necessary anyway..

Comment: To answer my own question, you do get a single commit with the head of each branch as a parent (including the branch being merged into). if one or more of the individual merges would be fast forward merges, then you don't get the head of the branch being merged into as a parent, because it's already in the history of one of the branches.

Comment: If there is a conflict, the merge will simply fail with the message `Should not be doing an Octopus.`. This is clearly one of the best error messages ever.

Comment: Can the fourth command be substituted with `git merge master`? I want to make sure I understand the difference between `git pull` and `git merge`.

Answer (score 14):

I would just "fetch" all of origin:

```
git fetch origin
```

now that it is in your repo you can merge the branches into master:

```
git checkout master

git merge origin/feature1 

git merge origin/feature2
```

now you can merge master into develop

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```

if you are going to commit back to origin then I would setup a local tracking branch so you can have local access and push directly to origin:

```
git branch --track origin/feature1 feature1
```