# How to manage multiple branches at the same time and merging

Tags: git

I tend to work with a master branch, and create a feature branch then I go back into master and merge the feature.

If I want to work on multiple features, I am fearing there will be allot of manual merging to do.

Scenerio:

1. in master branch
2. Create feature1 branch
3. back in master
4. create feature2 branch

Now say I finish feature2 first, and go back in master and merge feature2.

If I finish feature1 and try and merge, I think it will be messy correct?
Is there a way to get feature1 up-to-date from the master before I try and merge, or does it even make a difference?

If there is a better practise please tell me because that is the point of my question.

Comment: you'll probably want to start by merging master into feature1 and handle the conflicts there. Typically everytime you merge back a branch into master, you should merge master back into all the feature branch that may be affected by the changes you made.

Comment: If the two feature branches are targeting different areas of your application (e.g. a UI branch and a server side branch), and this is a good practice, then it might not make too much of a difference in which order you merge back.

Comment: Is your question similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292184/merging-multiple-branches-with-git) ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you will have conflicts since branch 2 is not "updated", BUT you can go to branch2 and update it (which means branch2 will now have the last changes) 
this is what is called rebase..

this image is more descriptive than my words..

[image]