# Git conflict between different branches

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge-conflict

I have different feature branches and one main branch:-

```
main
feature1
feature2
feature3
```

feature2 and feature3 branches are behind master by a few commits. Before that feature1 branch is ahead of the main branch.

Firstly feature3 needs to merged and then feature2.

I want to merge all the feature branches in a way that i dont lose the contents and moreover the new contents needs to be added. In the end the data of all the feature branch should be in the main branch.

I am confused like should I first merge the feature1 branch as its ahead of the main branch or first I merge feature3 first and feature2 into the feature1 branch and create a pull request from the feature1 branch. Also which are the commands that i can use in order to accomplish this?

The files in all feature 1, 2, 3 is modified and because of that i am facing merge conflict error.

What i did:- Firstly i created a dummy branch from the main branch. Merged the changes of feature3 branch in to the dummy branch. Now when i am trying to merge the feature2 branch into dummy branch doing so i am getting merge conflict error.

can someone guide me here?

Comment: If they are _really_ independent from each other, you can merge them in any order _from git's POV, at least_, git does not care. You might have other considerations in mind, that are not strictly VCS-related.... like _I will merge feature1 first because then I can pull those changes into feature2 so that I can then test a part of feature2 that is related... but not dependent_.

Comment: Besides what @eftshift0 said, you could combine these with an "octopus merge", which acts as a sort of proof that none of the three branches has any conflict with any of the others. But octopus merges are a bit tricky and don't do anything that regular merges don't do (in fact, the "sort of proof" above is because regular merges can do MORE than octopus merges can).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging multiple branches with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292184/merging-multiple-branches-with-git)

Comment: To test I created a example branch and merged feature3 first and then when i created pull request for feature 2 to merge into example branch I got this error Conflict: This file was modified on source and destination.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts, https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line, https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/resolve-merge-conflicts/

Answer (score 0):

You could bring `feature2` and `feature3` in sync with master again by rebasing them on master. Just be sure you pulled your master to the latest changes. Then checkout `feature3` and run `git rebase master`, now you could merge it into master, do the same with `feature2` and you are done.

Note: it does not really matter here if you merge `feature1` first or after. Just be sure to also rebase it, if you merge it after merging the other two branches.

Comment: To test I created a example branch and merged feature3 first and then when i created pull request for feature 2 to merge into example branch I got this error Conflict: This file was modified on source and destination @jugendhacker